# remove only one dash from a javascript list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to replace the hyphen that would be separated from the text. As attached :

1. GARE CENTRALE - HERRMANN-DEBROUX
2. GARE CENTRALE - MUSEE DU TRAM
3. HOPITAL ETTERBEEK-IXELLES - BORDET STATION
   I would like to have the list like that in list :
4. [GARE CENTRALE], [HERRMANN-DEBROUX]
5. GARE CENTRALE], [MUSEE DU TRAM]
6. [HOPITAL ETTERBEEK-IXELLES], [BORDET STATION]

I tried to use : `list.replace(/\-/,'');`
But it's only working with the first and two lines but doesn't work with the last, I don't want to do it manually cause there is like 100 lines and every line is different.

Thanks :D

Comment: Java != Javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like that if you want an array as a result.

```js
var array = [];
var texts = [
  'HOPITAL ETTERBEEK-IXELLES - BORDET STATION',
  'GARE CENTRALE - MUSEE DU TRAM',
  'HOPITAL ETTERBEEK-IXELLES - BORDET STATION'
];

texts.forEach((text) =>{
  array.push(text.split(' - '));
});
console.log(array);
```

Comment: Their is no way more easly like .replace() ?

Comment: @forcela What is so hard about this code. It looks pretty straight forward to me. You cna easily rewrite it as a simplified oneliner too `texts.forEach(text => array.push(text.split(' - ')));`. I don't see how `replace()` will solve your issues but if it does just add spaces to the regex?

Comment: @forcela You want a list as a result but `replace()` method only replaces the given strings in a string. So `split()` is the simpliest method i think :)

Comment: Yeah it's what I didn't detail, i replace string in a string but in an array like `var ligneNom = lines[i].split(',')[longNameLoca];` . But thank a lot for your help :)